# react layout not looking well

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, material-ui

i am working on a react application ,in which we have header on top, side navbar and footer usually each application have it. my application layout not look good.top header is fine but the page content goes always left side. 
below is my index.js code

```
import React ,{ Component } from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes.jsx';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import theme from './material_ui_raw_theme_file.jsx';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import NotFoundPage from './staticComponents/NotFoundPage.jsx';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore.jsx';
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer} from 'react-router-redux';
import App from './components/App.jsx';
import Home from './components/home.jsx';
import ProjectIndex from './pages/projectIndex.jsx';
import SignIn from './components/SignInForm.jsx';

//for React Developer Tools
window.React = React;

const store = configureStore();
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

injectTapEventPlugin();

render(
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={theme}>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component = {Home} />
        <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/project" component={ProjectIndex} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>
      </Route>  
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  , document.getElementById('body')
```

);

And App.jsx code is :-

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
     this.state = {
      logged: false,
    };
  }
  render() {

    return (
        <div className="page_container">
        <div>
        <AppBar
          title="Issue Tracker"
          iconElementRight={<Logged />}
        />
        </div>
        <div>     
          {this.props.children}
         </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And Home.jsx code is :-

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react';
class Home extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Hi this is home</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

and the out put is 
[image]

any help will be great.
thanks

Comment: We'll need to see the code of your components, and possibly a screenshot of the issue. The code you've provided is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add styles to the div where you inject your `props.children`, you can try something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
     this.state = {
      logged: false,
    };
  }
  render() {

    return (
        <div className="page_container">
        <div>
        <AppBar
          title="Issue Tracker"
          iconElementRight={<Logged />}
        />
        </div>
        <div className="main-content-wrapper">     
          {this.props.children}
         </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And in your css:

```
.main-content-wrapper {
    width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

or

```
.main-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Now is up to you to style it as you like it.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if thats the case :)